# Is it possible to pass a directive into state configuraton?

Tags: angularjs

I have an app with a directive called fightcard. In my app configuration, I'm using ui-router to change the state. This code works...

```
$stateProvider

    .state('matches', {
        url: '/matches',
        template: '<fightcard matches="matches"></fightcard>'
    })
```

But... I was wondering if there is a property on state like controller to simply pass in the directive instead of an html template. I'd like to do something like this:

```
  $stateProvider

    .state('matches', {
        url: '/matches',
        directive: 'fightcard',
        directiveModels: ['matches']
    })
```

The html template option isn't that terrible - it may actually be superior - just wondering if there is an alternative in more "angular way" or perhaps the html template is the preferred approach. Each match has sub views for the best of games... probably it's better to have the directives contained a simple html templates like so:

```
    $stateProvider

    .state('matches', {
        url: '/matches',
        templateUrl: 'partials/matches.html'
    })

    .state('matches.games', {
        url: '/games',
        templateUrl: 'partials/games.html'
    })
```

matches.html template

```
<fightcard matches="matches"></fightcard>
```

games.html template

```
<h6>BEST OF 5 GAMES</h6> 
<div ng-repeat="gameModel in games">
    <game gamemodel="gameModel" class="centerText"></game>
</div>
```

Comment: You could always extend .state() to allow that.

Answer (score 1):

Putting the directive in a template is *THE* way to use the directive in AngularJS.

If you wanted to get fancy, you could extend `.state()` using the `.decorator()` method of [$stateProvider](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider) to parse your special config and create that template for you, but it would really be a round-about way to go about using the directive.